# Is there a good Stack Exchange site to post more theoretical/hypothetical questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, off-topic

I was just wondering if there is a site, sort of like this one, but more geared towards hypothetical questions, such as those about numbers theory and such.

Mainly, I was just curious if there's any possible file over 1 Gig that has 0 statistical redundancy, but the "What should I ask here" section of the FAQ says to limit questions to practical, usable coding questions, and that seemed a little off-topic.

Comment: "0 percent *statistical* redundancy" sounds like a perfect fit for Cross Validated.  I'd try there.  If its a good question it will get migrated to the right site.

Comment: @casperOne Oh, good point. I just sort of have this ingrained idea that, for some strange reason, it's disproportionately awful to have a moderator use _any_ of his/her "Moderator Powers" on your submission. I suppose that comes from my previous life outside of the SE sites... :/

Comment: Well, Cross Validated could have been a choice, but gung has confirmed my suspicions that it's not a perfect fit.  This is more of a "discrete math" challenge than a statistics one.  Poke around CS (someone had recommended CS Theory, but I don't think they would consider this a research level question), there's a wide variety of problems of this ilk.

Comment: If it's for discrete mathematics, [it's certainly on topic for Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics).

Comment: Also, I'd get used to moderators affecting posts.  Not just moderators, but users have the ability to moderate posts to a degree based on reputation.  It's built into the core of the system, and while possibly a shock to those not used to it, works very well to improve quality, for the most part.  Just saying, don't be surprised by it.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like it's likely to be on topic on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).  It's in Beta, so their faq is still fairly general and encompasses:

> Computer Science - Stack Exchange is for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science.

Your question is in the same realm as ["Measuring entropy for a table"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/measuring-entropy-for-a-table-e-g-sql-results), which was considered to be on topic.

Comment: it might also be worth metioning cstheory.sx

Comment: I just did some looking, and I saw [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). The description _seems_ to make it look like the best one for my question, it says that questions related to "statistical analysis, applied or theoretical," "machine learning," and "probability theory" are on-topic, whereas CS says to only ask "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." I just want to know just so I can know, so I think that the first one would be better, but thanks for your help. (I usually begin some heavy research right after I post a question to an SE site.)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget CSTheory is for research-level problems, I don't think they would deem this on-topic there (not my philosophy, but that's their choice).