# Are hypothetical questions (about physics) suitable for any SE site?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have an interesting shower thought to share with the world, but none of the SE sites seem to suit this question perfectly.

> Lasers are coherent beams of light, traveling only in one direction. So how come we can see *some* lasers from the side? Are these not *true* lasers?

[This similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157525/is-there-a-good-stack-exchange-site-to-post-more-theoretical-hypothetical-questi) hovers around the same idea but the answer is specific to Computer Science.

I've considered [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), but this question is more of a random thought, rather than a serious scientific question.

Is there any site on Stack Exchange where this question would be appropriate?

Comment: I mean, I _would_ propose SE Shower Thoughts if Reddit users wouldn't break into my house and torture me.

Comment: Why don't you ask on the Physics Meta if such a question would be acceptable? If you want a certain style of answer, you could always outline it in your post.

Comment: FYI: Not all questions are suitable somewhere on Stack Exchange; some questions just aren't appropriate anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, for whatever reason.  Your post seems to start from the premise that if you have a question, surely it must be OK to post it on some SE site, and it's just a matter of finding which one.  But that's not the case -- not all questions have a home on the Stack Exchange network.  I've edited the post to remove that implicit premise.

Comment: Do note that every Stack Exchange site I've seen has [a help page that explains what kinds of questions are inappropriate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and it tends to include standard caveats like "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  Also, we have an expectation that you do a significant amount of research before asking.  Therefore, you shouldn't assume that "sharing your shower thoughts with the world" will necessarily be welcome or considered useful.

Comment: Note that this question **has already been asked on physics**, and a search for "why are lasers visible from the side" returns [What makes some laser beams visible and other laser beams invisible?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20259) (which answers your question) as the first result.

Comment: Related (on the meta question, not the physics one): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/162102

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Try Physics.**

Physics Stack Exchange doesn't just cater to physicists asking incomprehensible questions about relativistic quantum field theory. It's for people of all levels, asking about all sorts of questions. Just take a look at the front page.

Yours is fine. It's not technical, but that means nothing. It's a good one nonetheless. The answer is based on sound physical principles (scattering, by the way!); it's not some wacky hypothetical.

Physics does prohibit some fanciful questions, but only those that break laws of physics. Yours does not.

Comment: It would be fine if it wasn't a duplicate question [What makes some laser beams visible and other laser beams invisible?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20259) ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can ask on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) but don't be surprised if you question is closed as a duplicate.

[What makes some laser beams visible and other laser beams invisible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20259/what-makes-some-laser-beams-visible-and-other-laser-beams-invisible):

> What makes the beam of some lasers:
>
> 1. visible? such as the ones used in clubs or such as the laser pointers sold at amazon which if pointed to the sky look like a solid
>      visible beam of light crossing the sky (it reminds me of the
>      lightsaber in Star Wars).
> 2. invisible? such as the ones used in pointers for presentations.

It has 4 answers, one of which is accepted ...